# "Launch Failed. Binary Not Found." Eclipse C/C++ IDE issue. [Eclipse installed on Windows 7 working with Cygwin]

Tags: eclipse

### I have two problems :

One ] I don't know how to use Cygwin and not sure if I have installed it correctly and
Two] My Eclipse displaying error every time Im trying to run any cpp program.

Actually I have downloaded Cygwin for Netbeans IDE which also not working. Cpp programs giving errors and nothing is executing.

Can u please tell me how should I fix these and can u give me some links to tutorial sites ,ideas ,- anything on how to use these.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this will help you. But I found an answer that may be useful.

[Launch Failed Binary not found Eclipse for C in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407430/launch-failed-binary-not-found-eclipse-for-c-in-windows)