# Error when running a C code in eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I was trying my first c program in eclipse. Now after installing the c/c++ plugin i have c/c++ perspective.

But when I tried to run this simple C code, a window pops up titled "Application

Launcher", and it contains the following message: "Launch failed.Binary not found".

Please let me know if the mistake in the c code I wrote or in any something else.

**C code**:

```
#include <iostream.h>

main() {
    cout<<"Hello world!\n";
}
```

Comment: That's C++, not C.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407430/launch-failed-binary-not-found-eclipse-for-c-in-windows

Comment: First work out what C is.

Comment: You have a couple of errors in your code (if you named your file with the proper extension, otherwise you have a lot of errors). Because of this it will not build, and no program will be generated, leading to the failed launch because no program was found.

Comment: Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers does not contain a compiler or debugger; if your system does not have one, you need to download and install one.

Answer (score 0):

the code you put is C++ code and not C code.

with Eclipse you have first to create new project:

`File` --> `New` --> `C++ Project` --> `Executable` --> `Emptyproject`

Give a name to your project and then continue the setting till finish the creation of the project

Edit your C++ source code and then build your project with

`Project` --> `Build All`

And then run your binary with the famous green button. or with:

`Run` --> `Run`

Answer (score 0):

Correct C++ code is

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout<<"Hello world!\n";
}
```

Note it's `<iostream>` not `<iostream.h>`, `std::cout` not `cout`, and `int main` not `main`. These mistakes seem to indicate you are learning C++ from a very out of date source.

Answer (score 0):

That's not C; it's an ancient dialect of C++, which a modern compiler will probably reject even if you don't try to build it as C.

A "hello world" in C might look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}
```

and in this century's dialects of C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
}
```

Now you should decide whether to learn C or C++ (which are very different languages), and find a good book on the subject. For C++, start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242).