# Issues running C++ code on Eclipse - Using Lynda tutorials to learn

Tags: c++

I have just started teaching myself C++ and am already having issues with running the code. I am using Lynda.com to learn and watching the videos. I have downloaded Eclipse as well as the other proper files.

However, the eclipse I have downloaded is different from the video and it is hard to follow along. For instance, I cannot figure out how to Run Testing properly or if I have even uploaded the code properly from the exercise files.

The issue I keep getting is "Launch Failed. Binary not found."

This is very frustrating as I am not sure how to get around Eclipse at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried attaching pictures but I do not have enough reputation. Sorry.

Comment: Which version of eclipse have you downloaded and from?

Comment: Hey Jack, I am using this one: 

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Kepler Release
Build id: 20130614-0229

Comment: What kind of project are you using? Can you tell if the build passed?

Comment: I started a C/C++ project and wanted to import files from an exercise that I got from Lynda.com. The build finishes but it has errors. When the instructor does them on the video there are no errors and it runs clean. I am simply trying to run a test program of Hello, World!

Comment: Right - your build has errors, that's why the binary cannot be found. You'll need to fix the compile errors first. If you want, you can update your answer to show the output from the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

The following are the things you need to make sure they are set:

Windows > Preferences > C/C++ > New CDT project wizard > Makefile Project > Binary Parsers

a) Set it to Windows PE Parser if you are on windows.

b) Set it to Cygwin PE Parser if you are using Cygwin

Windows > Preferences > C/C++ > Environment

Now click on "select" and select "Path" variable so that you add you path variables in Eclipse.

ADVICE FROM HERE: [Launch Failed Binary not found Eclipse for C in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407430/launch-failed-binary-not-found-eclipse-for-c-in-windows)

Comment: I tried that but the settings are different for this version of Eclipse so I cannot follow the steps. There is no "New CDT Project Wizard" or Environment under C/C++