# Launch failed. Binary not found. Why?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I am on Windows 7 32 bit using Eclipse Juno. I have installed the CDT plugin. I have also installed `Cygwin` and the necessary files from packages like `gdb`, `gcc`, `gawk`, `make` etc.

I still get a `Binary Not Found` error. I had a look at this question
[Launch Failed Binary not found Eclipse for C in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407430/launch-failed-binary-not-found-eclipse-for-c-in-windows) tried everything but there seems to be no solution for it.

What is going wrong ?

Comment: Did you get a compiled binary using 'Build Project' (instead of directly using 'Run' or 'Debug')??

Comment: When using Cygwin on Windows7, I was experiencing I couldn't get stuff compiling and debugging properly, when I didn't start eclipse from a Cygwin shell.

Comment: @g-makulik how do I start eclipse from the Cygwin shell ?

Comment: Just start a Cygwin shell window and type in the path to your eclipse installation's executable (append a `&` character to run it as background process). Use `/cygdrive/<x>` to refer to windows drive character `x:`.

Comment: @g-makulik Can you gimme a complete example ? :)

Comment: I have actually removed Cygwin from my windows installation, but it should be something like this: `> "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/eclipse/eclipse.exe"&`

Comment: Tried. Didnt work. I just got a few more blank `>` on next line

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37363/discussion-between-g-makulik-and-little-child)

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple reasons for this :

First : Select Preference (click on Eclipse in MAC machine left top OR Windows from menu in Windows OS to find preferences) --> C/C++ --> New c/c++project wizard--> change to MACOS GCC (for mac) or Cygwin GCC (for windows)

Second : I had the similar issue but code was different. In File.h file make sure

```
virtual ~Destructor () {}; //Don't forget Curly braces {}
```

Above statement shows destructor initialized () and defined with curly braces { } . In my code I forgot to define Destructor. 
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> New C/C++ Project Wizard -> Makefile Project.

Choose one the following parsers and try with a new project.

1. PE Windows parser
2. Cygwin PE parser

Answer (score 0):

I was also receiving "Launch failed. Binary not found." My problem was AVAST Anti-virus. My Hello World C program would compile in eclipse CDT using the Windows PE Parser and mingw gcc compiler, but there was NO EXE FILE!!!! AVAST Antivirus was identifying the exe file as a false positive and removing it....grrrrr. The solution was to add the eclipse workspace folder to the exclusions list. Voila!! Eclipse generated my test.exe file.

Answer (score 0):

Run eclipse from a cygwin shell :

pathToEclipse/eclipse.exe

Choose compilator cygwin Gcc when you build a new project.

Build and Run work now.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to the project(main manu)-> Build all
This will solve your problem.