# console is not displaying output in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

i'm new to Eclipse IDE.i installed eclipse on my windows.i'm trying to develop a  c/c++ new project on it.At the begining time i got the error "Launch Failed Binary not found eclipse for C in windows" ,for that i follwed these steps. 
[Launch Failed Binary not found Eclipse for C in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407430/launch-failed-binary-not-found-eclipse-for-c-in-windows])

but after following the steps the error is rectified.but after doing "run"in my eclipse, console is not giving any output for sample c code.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it that the code runs but you are not seeing the console? Might need to add getch() at the end just to pause the screen so that you can see the output.

Comment: check window-->show View --> console

Comment: If you are coding in c please get rid of the java and c++ tags

Comment: Are you using C or C++? It seems to me that you can be using only either one of these, not both (although you can combine many C and C++ files into a single project). And why did you tag the question as "Java"? I don't see anything Java-related in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to IDE:s I recomend using DevC++. There is almost no manuall installations. Just download and start programming. [Download page](http://www.bloodshed.net/dev/devcpp.html).

Comment: If the answer would a software recommendation, then the question would be looking for a tool. In that case the question would be off-topic and you should not answer but flag as off-topic.