# Running C Programs on Eclipse Luna Encountered Error - Binaries Not Found

Tags: c, eclipse

I'm trying to run a C program on eclipse Luna but when I try to run it, a window pops up telling "Launch Failed. Binary not found."

I am new to C programming and would to run my first program.

My Operating System is Windows 8.1 if that is relevant.

Are there any alternatives besides Eclipse I can use to run my C program if I am not able to resolve my problem?

Errors at `**include<>**`

```
// Unresolved inclusion: < stdio.h >
```

In the menu: 
Windows > Preferences > C/C++ > New CDT project wizard > Makefile Project > Binary Parsers, 
I set it to Windows PE Parser

In Windows > Preferences > C/C++ > Build > Environment,
I selected Path variable

Finally hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to build Binary file

Unfortunately both didn't work, still same error is popping up
"Launch Failed. Binary not found."

Comment: This seems to address this sort of issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407430/launch-failed-binary-not-found-eclipse-for-c-in-windows . From what I can tell, it's likely you're missing the compiler(s) or the IDE isn't finding them.

Comment: I installed the C compiler MinGW for Windows but don't know how to configure the path to Eclipse although I have looked at this forum.

Comment: To answer your side question, I use NetBeans, and I prefer it to Eclipse. It's been a while since I used Eclipse, so unfortunately I can't be much more helpful regarding your main question, as this does indeed seem more complicated than a missing compiler.

Comment: A few clicks on eclipse leads to the entry fields for the included header files path(s).   This should be a 'one time' setup for the system files.  For header files you have written, you may have to tweak the path for each new project.  If you always architect your projects the same way (always a good practice) then it should be a 'one time' setup, using relative directory paths.