# "Launch failed. Binary not found" when running a fortran code

Tags: eclipse, fortran

I try to run the next fortran code in Eclipse-Fortran and get the error:
"Launch failed. Binary not found." 
Can you please tell me what might be the problem?

```
program P1
A=17.34
B=27.6E-2
K=23
P=(A-B)/0.42
Q=P*B+2
M=(K-6)/4
N=A
I=(M+N)**2
write(6,1)A,B,P,Q
1 format (1H 4E15.4)
write(6,2)K,M,N,I
2 format (1H 4I15)
stop
end
```

Comment: Did you actually compile it?

Comment: Kind of duplicate, does this answer help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9962046/577108

Comment: While it may or may not be related can I ask why in the world you are using hollerith edit descriptors? They were made obsolete by f77 (thirty years ago) and were explicitly deleted from the standard at least ten years ago.

Comment: How did you compile and execute it?

Comment: I guess the problem was that I didn't use the new-> fortran source file option to add the file to the project, and didn't use the extension f90. When I did it and built the project I got compilation errors. It seems that Eclipse doesn't support Fortran IV.

Comment: the only thing making that "fortran IV" is that format, change to `format(' ',4E15.4)`