# C Program Execution

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I've downloaded Eclipse C/C++ IDE . I need to run a simple c program in this(To print welcome).

While trying to run the program its popping up an error message like "Launch failed: Binary not found" .

Please help me out.Thanks

Comment: Really? That's all you are going to tell us? Anyway, have you even bothered to search before asking? If none of the previously asked questions helped you then you need to say what you have tried. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407430/launch-failed-binary-not-found-eclipse-for-c-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse on Unix based machine you have to make an object file for C programs before compilation.If you didn't make object file then it doesn't have the required binary numbers to execute.
So try "Ctrl+B" it will build the program in Eclipse.

I advice you to use netbeans, which is far better then Eclipse...Further it's your choice..

Happy Coding.:)

Comment: Thanks for your  comment. But I just want to try in the eclipse.  I have tried build option then I got 'include' but still  could not load associate binary file. Do you know how to make an object file?  and Moreover I'll try in Netbeans then.