# Eclipse C++ IDE, Issues setting up

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm having issues with setting up Eclipse for C++ editing.  I am using Cygwin and Eclipse (obviously), and I've gotten to the point of making the example project Hello World.  However, when I try to create a new project I always get the message "Launch Failed. Binary Not Found".  I know this is a common issue, but why would the default hello world project work and not mine?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

- First  Build the project ( project menu in navigation bar)
- then, A new folder named Binaries will appear now in project explorer.   (refresh if needed)
- Now you can try running your project, and no errors will appear.

more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407430/launch-failed-binary-not-found-eclipse-for-c-in-windows)

Comment: did you followed instructions from the link i mentioned?